# Which are the differences between Java entities and Java beans?

Tags: jakarta-ee, model

In Jakarta context, I would like to know the differences between those concepts.

As far as I know, Java entities represent entities of databases.
On the other side, beans are like an abstraction of entities.

But I still do not get what "an abstraction of entities" means, and which is the usefulness of using beans, insead of simply using entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Entities is a ORM concept JPA in jakarta domain. Java beans is more broader concept.

> ```
> A JavaBean is a Java class that should follow the following conventions:
>
>     It should have a no-arg constructor.
>     It should be Serializable.
>     It should provide methods to set and get the values of the properties, known as getter and setter methods.
> ```

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-bean

Any java class that conforms these rules is Java Bean it can be a Java Entity too.

Entities are java classes which represents persistable domain objects. They are either annotated with @Entity or specified with configuration file to persist java objects and retrieve it from a datastore. Therefor fixing object relational impedance mismatch to think and work with persistent datasource with ease of mind.